# How to exclude undesired descendants?

Tags: javascript, module, filter, generics, descendant

I have a situation where an element contains `n` clickable handles and `n` revealable elements:

```
<div class="revealer">
  <div class="hotspot">
    <a class="handle" href="javascript:;">A</a>
    <div class="reveal">
      <p>Content A.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal">
      <p>Content B.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click 'handle', it shows both 'reveal' elements. This works fine. This chunk of code is dropped into a given document wherever the creator wants. Including... inside another `<div class="reveal"></div>` element. The ability to nest these revealer objects is reasonable, and useful in my case.

What I'm stuck on, is a decent way to only handle only immediate `<div class="reveal"></div>` elements, and not nested ones (otherwise clicking on the outer handle would reveal alll nested reveals).

So here's the example structure:

---

```
<div class="revealer">
  <div class="hotspot">
    <a class="handle" href="javascript:;">A</a>
    <div class="reveal">
      <p>Content A.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal">

        <p>Content B.</p>

        <!-- nested revealer -->
        <div class="revealer">
          <div class="hotspot">
            <a class="handle" href="javascript:;">A</a>
            <div class="reveal">
              <p>Sub-content A.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
              <p>Sub-content B.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> // a setup script which instantiates a Module object for this revealer, which controls all revealing </script>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> // a setup script, which instantiates a Module object for this revealer, which controls all revealing </script>
```

---

I heavily use the YUI2.8.2 framework, so right now I have a test in place when you click a handle to collect a set of its own revealers and show them, but excluding nested reveals, which should be actioned by their own instantiated module, not the parents'.

The Javascript test is as follows:

```
    // grab all 'reveal' elements to show
    var reveals = yd.getElementsBy(function(el){
            if( yd.hasClass(el, REVEAL_CLASS) && pObj.isChild( el ) ){
                return true ;
            }
            return false;
    }, null, this.root() );


    // the test method above is "isChild( el )", the 'el' arg is a 'handle' inside a 'hotspot', so I have...

isChild: function( el )
{
    var ancestor = yd.getAncestorBy( el, function(nestedEl){
        return yd.hasClass(nestedEl, REVEALER_CLASS);
    });

    // ancestor is the immediate parent 'reveal' element
    var forefather = yd.getAncestorBy( ancestor, function(nestedEl){
        return yd.hasClass(nestedEl, REVEALER_CLASS);
    });

    // forefather is 
    if(forefather){
        // Yuck yuck yuck, get rid of this dependency on a custom className :(
        if(!yd.hasClass(this.getRoot(), 'revealer-nested') ){
            return false ;
        }
    }
    return true ;
},
```

But all I can muster is to add a new class name, `revealer-nested`, to a nested `revealer` element... but I *really* don't want to have to do that, because these objects are supposed to exist in their own context and not care or be affected by parent revealers.

... I hope that isn't tmi, please ask any required questions etc for more info - I may have missed out some contextual info as I'm right in the middle of refactoring this module.

Many, many thanks in advance.

EDIT:
It's also quite important that I don't start relying on descendant properties like parentNode, childNode[x], nextSibling, etc ... because currently this module is quite flexible in that its 'reveal' and 'handle' elements can reside within other markup and still be targeted - so long as they're found inside a 'hotspot'.

Comment: Hrm, the code coloring doesn't look quite right for me, and I can't see any markup errors - but I did type that abridged chunk of HTML in manually - rest assured it is valid code in my situation.

Comment: Maybe I understood it wrong but you only need to show the `reveal` objets that are at the same level (thus, siblings) as (of) the `handle`. I don't know YUI though.

Comment: You're right, and I haven't expressed this in the question - but really I've built my module in such a way that reveal elements and handles could in theory sit inside x level of markup and still be targeted correctly. So I'm using YUI to grab only the elements I need, instead of relying on node positioning like parentNode, nextSibling, etc. I'll add that to the question methinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS3 selector :not() which allows you to filter out elements from a selection.  I know jQuery can select a set of elements by CSS3 selector, for example:

```
$('.revealer:not(.revealer > .revealer)')
```

I think that would work as a selector to only select elements of class "revealer" which aren't children of class "revealer".

This all depends on YUI being able to support CSS3 selectors to select sets of elements (if you're definitely only using YUI).

Does that help?  I think that's what you were asking...

Comment: Ooooh, my bad, is that going to work in IE6? (lol, cry, *bang*). Actually, one of the reasons I am even refactoring this module is include our own much smaller sized widgets which use only the YUI base framework - for the express purpose of reducing HTTP requests (cant use YUI combo btw). I'm combining 4 modules into one to achieve this, so adding another lib dependency (jquery/other) isn't the best option... but I suppose it might have to do if nothing already available works. Note, i don't necessarily need the YUI code as an answer, just the general logic would do and I'll YUI-ise it.

Comment: Not to derail you though, yes, that is in theory what I want, so long as that's going to be intensely crossbrowser.

Comment: When jQuery does this, it's not actually relying on CSS3 in the browser - it implements the functionality using JavaScript.  From jQuery's website, the entire jQuery library is compatible with: IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+, Chrome.  Also, YUI probably has a CSS3 selector set built in somewhere... but I'm not sure about YUI's cross-browser compatibility, as I've never used it.

Comment: Gotchya, stupid mistake of mine. YUI has the Selector utility, which I have working now. I've tried a few things, like: "#_revealerEl_0 .handle:not(#_revealerEl_0 .reveal .handle)" (the id attribute of a 'revealer' div being applied dynamically). What its doing is continuing to select all handles within reveals, and isn't excluding based on the :not selector. I'm currently searching for sample usages for this, not having much luck - do you have a decent resource for CSS3 selectors, like not(), because i think we're almost there!

Comment: Until I get some more info on the YUI2.8.1 Selector utility, i've included jquery - same result as YUI so I'd say my selecting is incorrect. Here's the string I combine to select with:  #_revealerEl_0 .handle:not(#_revealerEl_0 .reveal .handle)  . So my thinking here is "All handles inside _revealerEl_0, except any found inside its nested revealer(s)".

Comment: Ok, I got this working with YUI; I was not quite selecting properly but using your example I'e solved it -- many thanks for the lesson on CSS3 selectors, very powerful.