# What's the jquery selector for excluding nested descendents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, yui

[Per my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663793/how-to-exclude-undesired-descendants), which has turned to jquery to solve this, but which may be worked back into YUI if I get my thinking straight, I need a selector to exclude descendents.

The solution proposed says something like this:

```
$( '.revealer:not(.revealer > .revealer)' );
```

To fit more accurately with my situation, because I have multiple HTML chunks to perform the same test on, I have updated it be:

```
$( '#_revealerEl_0 .handle:not(#_revealerEl_0 .reveal .handle)' );
```

The HTML its selecting on (image there are numerous copies of this same chunk on a page, each needing to be treated alone - an id attribute is assigned to each 'revealer'):

```
<div class="revealer" id="#_revealerEl_0">
  <div class="hotspot">
    <a class="handle" href="javascript:;">A</a>
    <div class="reveal">
      <p>Content A.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="reveal">

        <p>Content B.</p>

        <!-- nested revealer -->
        <div class="revealer">
          <div class="hotspot">
            <a class="handle" href="javascript:;">A</a>
            <div class="reveal">
              <p>Sub-content A.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="reveal">
              <p>Sub-content B.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In a nutshell: I need to target 'top level' handles within a 'hotspot', per revealer - and no nested descendents with the same class names.

thanks,
d

EDIT:

It's also quite important that I don't start relying on descendant properties like parentNode, childNode[x], nextSibling, etc ... because currently this module is quite flexible in that its 'reveal' and 'handle' elements can reside within other markup and still be targeted - so long as they're found inside a 'hotspot'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude undesired descendants?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663793/how-to-exclude-undesired-descendants)

Comment: You should edit in extra detail to your last question instead of asking a new one which addresses the exact same problem.

Comment: One's using YUI (preferred), one's using jquery - i'm restricted to 5 tags, and i've linked them both together openly. Sure go ahead and close, whatev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which is your `#_revealerEl_0` element, but if it's your top-level `.revealer`, can't you just do this?

```
$('#_revealerEl_0 > .hotspot > .handle')
```

Or if the top-level `.revealer` is itself a descendant of `#_revealerEl_0`, then this works:

```
$('#_revealerEl_0 > .revealer > .hotspot > .handle')
```

The basic premise here is that you chain multiple `>` child combinators.

Comment: I've amended my code above to have the id, sorry, it doesn't have it until my module is instantiated, but from my tests wrt the other SO question mentioned here - your code will continue to target *nested* 'revealer' containers. I need to harvest all handles (there could be multiple handle classed elements), but *not* handles inside a *nested* revealer.

Comment: I solved this with YUI, using the jquery way of thinking - but as a lesson in CSS3 selecting I continued to try and implement some of these solutions out of interest. Though honestly I couldn't get any of these to pick up, I'd assume they work in a cleaner situation where there might not be so much going on. Either way, the reading I've done around all of your suggestions has been very interesting - so thanks for all of your help peeps.

Comment: Ok, rewind (read: can't edit my last comment), "I did get your first suggestion to work now - it does so wonderfully".

Comment: @Danjah as my answer and comment inform though, the > selector will only find direct children, not the first child. Therefore RHS.parentNode() == LHS. Will this work in all situations?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         obj = $('.revealer[id*="revealerEl"]');
    //this will give you what you are after
     result = $("> .hotspot > .handle",obj)

    //if you want to see them in red
         $("> .hotspot > .handle",obj).css('color','red');

//or assign a click to it
 $("> .hotspot > .handle",obj).click(function(){
//blah ....
})
```

Comment: I have all of that. I'm after the correct selector to target all potential 'handle' classed elements within a 'hotspot', within a 'revealer' - but *not* handles found within a 'revealer' when it is nested inside another 'revealer'.

Comment: i've edited my question to reflect the importance of not relying on sibling/parent/child relationships, from my other question, because in theory with the large and clunky code I currently have (and am trying to clean up) I can add extra markup to these objects whenever i want and their functionality remains the same because they're class-targeted.

Comment: I changed my answer  to address your problem.

Comment: This looked succinct and what I'm after, but didn't appear to target what I wanted. Here's the code I ran:
var obj = $('.revealer[id*="'+this.id()+'"]');
log(dump( $("> .hotspot > .handle",obj).css('color','red') ));

Where this.id() fetches the element's id (let's say its '_revealerEl_0' as per my example), the output from YUI's object dump on the jquery selection was:
{length => 0, prevObject => {length => 0}}

Comment: it returned null because your obj definition will return null. Your obj has to accurately return all revealers with an id, in your example  this.id() will return null as there is no this in this context...

Comment: You can try returning all revealers with an id set using obj = $('.revealer[id]'); or the def that i supplied which will match all ids with a specific string in it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using jQuery:

```
$('.revealer:first > .hotspot > .reveal')
```

Given the first revealer, find any hotspots that are DIRECT children, and find any DIRECT reveal items within.

So, to assign handlers to your 'handles':

```
$('.handle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.hotspot > .reveal').show();
});
```

The above translates to:

- For any given handle, assign a click event function to the element
- When a handle is clicked, find its closest parent hotspot
- From the hotspot, find any reveal elements that are direct children of the hotspot
- Show those elements if they were hidden with display: none.

Comment: This seems very neat, and something I'd use a lot, can you tell me - by 'direct' do you literally mean 'the element directly preceding', in that it must be essentially 'parentNode'? Hopefully not, because I'd definitely find use for this.

Comment: @Danjah it'd be worth exploring the jquery documentation on selectors, as it is very thorough. The > syntax means that the RHS.parentNode == LHS. So reveal.parentNode == hotspot. If hotspot isn't guaranteed to be the parent, then obviously this won't work.